# luis intent and entity detection of slack data into chat bot

Tags: node.js, slack, azure-language-understanding

I am using Node Js
example
Lets say user is sending data from slack to chat bot. so chat bot will detect intent and entity from data and then perform certain action based on intent.

I already created model in luis.
I am able to communicate between bot and slack.but how i can use my model to detect entities and intent.???

Comment: Please update your question to include a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look to the the [Luis Node.js sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/Node/intelligence-LUIS) to get an idea of how this should be.